# How should I use Facebook Open Graph?

Tags: seo, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I just put the link of my facebook account on the site. I did an SEO analysis from a free SEO site and it said I need to add Facebook Open Graph. And I add this:

```html
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.facebook.com/censored:)/">
```

Comment: I think to use it, is not only used in Facebook but also social media in general. don't use your FB profile is your website IF is for other things (I know you want self-promoting but `og:url` is not created for this) open graph help when your website is shared on social media, if the image and title is good, then you can have more click on the shared post

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas I got it. So which tag will I use?

Comment: I try to put you all the meta tag I will find for you, one minute :)

Comment: I posted now an answer, with all meta tags, I raw the code from an old my GitHub gist

Comment: Search engines don't use open graph tags.  The tag you added is for social media optimization (SMO), not for search engine optimization (SEO.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the comment, you tell me, *what other meta tags are there?* .

so here are the SEO tags I find for now

all here in this [github repo](https://github.com/Laaouatni/myCode/blob/main/HTML-CSS/RisorseProgrammazioneHTML/TAG/!DOCTYPE/doctypeConSeoMeta.html) or in the code below

you don't need to use all, do a mini-research, heres good point of start

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Primary Meta Tags -->
    <title>Laaouatni — HTML and CSS Project.</title>
    <meta name="title" content="Laaouatni — HTML and CSS Project.">
    <meta name="description" content="progetto HTML e CSS di Laaouatni Anas. codice su Github e Codepen (100% responsive)">

    <!-- css links -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./index.css">

    <!-- Open Graph / Facebook -->
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://laaouatni.github.io/">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Laaouatni - Technical Documentation Project.">
    <meta property="og:description" content="progetto HTML e CSS di Laaouatni Anas. codice su Github e Codepen (100% responsive)">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/87947051?v=4">

    <!-- Twitter -->
    <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
    <meta property="twitter:url" content="https://laaouatni.github.io/">
    <meta property="twitter:title" content="Laaouatni - Technical Documentation Project.">
    <meta property="twitter:description" content="progetto HTML e CSS di Laaouatni Anas. codice su Github e Codepen (100% responsive)">
    <meta property="twitter:image" content="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/87947051?v=4">

    <!-- font google api link -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- icon for html -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpeg" href="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/87947051?v=4" />
    <link rel="icon" href="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/87947051?v=4" type="image/jpeg" />

    <!-- other meta tags -->
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
    <meta name="robots" content="max-image-preview:large">
    <meta name="author" content="laaouatni" />
    <meta name="copyright" content="laaouatni" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="laaouatni, laaouatni anas, anas laaouatni, laaouatni html, laaouatni css, laaouatni javascript, laouatni, laoatni, laouatni anas">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="laaouatni">

    <!-- android meta tags -->
    <meta name="application-name" content="laaouatni">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#0000ff">

    <!-- IOS Seo Meta Tag -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#0000ff">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="48x48" href="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/87947051?v=4" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/87947051?v=4" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/87947051?v=4">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="96x96" href="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/87947051?v=4" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/87947051?v=4">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/87947051?v=4" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/87947051?v=4">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="192x192" href="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/87947051?v=4" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="256x256" href="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/87947051?v=4" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="384x384" href="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/87947051?v=4" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="512x512" href="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/87947051?v=4" />

    <!-- microsoft meta icon logo -->
    <meta name="msapplication-square310x310logo" content="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/87947051?v=4">
</head>




</html>
```